# Sorting lists with multiple restrictions

Tags: python, python-2.7

There are 6 players competing in a duo-system sport, I'm trying to find an algorithm to match the best pairs.

The restrictions are as follow: Player cannot play a player which is in his Cannot Play list, and needs to play the best match according to the Best Play list. So Player 1 best match for the next round is Player 3 and the worst is Player 4.

I'm figure out a smart way to have an optimal pairing system.

```
Player 1: Cannot Play(1,2,6) ; Best Play(3,5,4)  
Player 2: Cannot Play(2,1,5) ; Best Play(4,3,6)  
Player 3: Cannot Play(3,2,4) ; Best Play(1,5,6)  
Player 4: Cannot Play(4,3,6) ; Best Play(2,6,1)  
Player 5: Cannot Play(5,3,6) ; Best Play(3,4,1)  
Player 6: Cannot Play(6,4,5) ; Best Play(2,1,3)
```

Note in this example that you can assign quickly between P1 to P3, and then P2 to P4, but then you get stuck because P5 cannot play P6.

EDIT: I tried the below so far. However I'm trying to figure out the overall approach to the problem, not the solution to my code. My problem in the code is that sometimes the last pair cannot play against eachother, and I get no assigning for them:

```
swissPair=[]
cannot_play_against=[]
DB = psycopg2.connect("dbname=tournament")
c = DB.cursor()

standings = playerStandings()

# Assigning pairs
for player in standings:

    # Building a list of players player[0] won't be playing:
    # 1. Players already played 2. Players that are already assigned

    c.execute("SELECT loser from matches where winner=" + str(player[0]))
    lost_against = list(c.fetchall())
    c.execute("SELECT winner from matches where loser=" + str(player[0]))
    won_against = list(c.fetchall())
    already_assigned = [(i[0],) for i in swissPair] + [(i[2],) for i in swissPair]
    cannot_play_against = set(won_against + lost_against + already_assigned)

    # Making sure the player is not already assigned
    if (player[0],) not in already_assigned:

        # Creating a table sorted by (absolute winnings-player winnings)
        # By doing it we find opponents at the player's level
        c.execute("SELECT id, name, wins, abs(wins-" + str(player[2]) + ") from standings order by abs")
        list_by_distance = list(c.fetchall())
        # Removing those who can't play the player and the player himself
        can_play_against = [z for z in list_by_distance if z[:1] not in cannot_play_against and z[0]<>player[0]]

        if len(can_play_against)>0: swissPair.append((player[0],player[1],can_play_against[0][0],can_play_against[0][1]))  

        # In case all the pairs has been assigned: break
        if len(swissPair) == len(standings)/2: break

DB.close()
return swissPair
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can we see some code? How is your data represented? What kind of output are you looking for?

Comment: Sure, I'll post it in an EDIT now.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the code and just talking process:
You could try manually breaking up earlier pairings if there are no choices left later on; i.e. something like:

1. P1 matches P3, assign.
2. P2 matches P4, assign.
3. (P3 is already assigned.)
4. (P4 is already assigned.)
5. P5 has no candidates left -- best candidate is P3. Break P1/P3 pairing, new pair is P5/P3. P1 unassigned again.
6. P6 matches P1, assign.

I'm not sure this process is guaranteed to complete in all possible scenarios, you *may* have to extend it to keep track of earlier pairs that got made and prevent them from getting re-created to stop cycles from happening.